# FirebaseApp reinitialisation error on creating instance for second FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have used second firebase database as following:-

```
public class Volunteer extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseOptions options;
FirebaseApp secondApp;
FirebaseDatabase secondDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_volunteer);

    options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApiKey("AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxfGvao3w").setApplicationId("1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/").build();
    secondApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options, "second app");
    secondDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondApp);
    String key = secondDatabase.getReference().push().getKey();      }
}
```

Here, it works fine, but when this page is recalled i.e. when I startActivity again, onCreate() get called and it throws error:-

> error: firebase second app already exists!

So, how can I run that activity again without causing error. I tried to catch exception and also to check if app is already initialized, but then error that "secondDatabase" not getting instance come at:-

> secondDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondApp);

How can I initialize "secondApp" only once or how can I find old instance of initialized FirebaseApp so that on second time I can use that instance for "secondDatabase"?

Comment: Create a Application Class, then put your Firebase App Initialization there

Comment: I'd recommend injecting your `FirebaseApp` and `FirebaseDatabase` instances using Dagger.

Answer (score 0):

First check for the instance of second app and then initialize only if instance returned is null

Comment: As i written in question, I have done this but then error occurred at "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondApp);" on second time activity called because FirebaseDatabase can't get previous Instance.